# How to set the "app_version" for React Native Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Expo to build a react native project. I am taking advantage of Expo Updates to push updates OTA. When an update is created it uses the app version (as found in the package.json) to target a "runtime version" - meaning this update will only work for binaries built with that version.

This is fine but when I create a new update on an existing runtime, I also create a new commit and tag incrementing the package.json version, but this new version is not being reflected in analytics

[image: App screen shot showing v4.0.1]
[image: package.json version]
[image: firebase analytics showing only v4.0.0]

As you can see, the latest release version is v4.0.0, despite having a release for v4.0.1 (and many more by now) and I have tested this in debug view and my v4.0.1 is logging as a 4.0.0.

Is there a way to set the app_version manually? I have searched the repo but I cannot find the part which determines the app version.

The only thing I can think is that the app_version is "baked in" when building the binary and react-native-firebase/analytics is using this - which isn't always going to be the version when using Expo Updates or any other OTA updates.
Can anyone confirm if this is correct? And if so, I think it is fine to be the default, but is it possible to allow the developer tell the version to show as in Firestore Analytics?
Thanks